# Reading a CSV File in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am using Cloudera CDH3 Pseudo mode Cluster. In CDH3 The Pig Version is 0.8

I would like to read a CSV or Excel File Using Pig script

I downloaded piggybank-0.11.0.jar and kept it inside /home/cloudera/ directory

my csv file is like this..

```
id    name       city
100   surrender  Chennai
101   raja       Chennai
```

My Pig script is below

```
REGISTER '/home/cloudera/piggybank-0.11.0.jar';

A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/sample_rec.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage(',') AS (id:int,name:chararray,city:chararray);
B = DUMP A;
```

But I am getting below error

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CSVExcelStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.
```

Do I need to download piggbank jar for pig 0.8 version?

What is wrong here?
Is it possible to read csv file in pig 0.8 version?

Comment: 1. Unjar and see if you are having CSVExcelStorage class. 2. "," is the default delimiter for CSVExcelStorage, we need not specify the same.

Comment: 3. Specify complete package name while using CSVExcelStorage() : USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify complete package name while using CSVExcelStorage() :

```
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage() AS ...
```

Other Checks :

1. Unjar and see if you are having CSVExcelStorage class.
2. "," is the default delimiter for CSVExcelStorage, we need not specify the same.

Other alternative is to make use of CSVLoader

```
 A = LOAD 'a.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader() AS (f1,f2,f3);
```

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html

Comment: Ok.. I tried  that , but it gives some junk  records when I dump the ouput  I am using Pig 0.8 inside cdh3.. but I am also using piggybank-0.11.0.jar . Is that the problem, CSVExcelStorage is available with Pig 0.8?

Comment: @SurenderRaja: Can you use CSVLoader instead ? Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html

Comment: ok..i am trying the below code        Input(s):
Successfully read 52 records (9205 bytes) from: "/user/cloudera/inputfiles/sample_rec.csv"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 52 records (1171 bytes) in: "hdfs://localhost/tmp/temp1988488632/tmp-1068001496"


(,,)
(,���o8u����+�`�ӡ���`��B[��lC|�,)
(,,)
(,,)
(,;�,)
(,,)

Comment: ok..i am trying the below codeREGISTER '/home/cloudera/surender/mapreducejars/piggybank-0.11.0.jar'; A  = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/sample_rec.csv' USINGorg.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader() AS(id:int,name:chararray,city:chararray);
dump A;                                                                                                       Input(s):
Successfully read 52 records (9205 bytes) from: "/user/cloudera/inputfiles/sample_rec.csv"
Output(s)
Successfully stored 52 records (1171 bytes)in: "hdfs://localhost/tmp/temp1988488632/tmp-1068001496"
(,���o8u����+�`�ӡ���`��B[��lC|�,)

Comment: My question is  whether '/home/cloudera/surender/mapreducejars/piggybank-0.11.0.jar' works in Cloudera CDH3 or not?